# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Tags: python, lxml

This is what i have, this code will generate an Xml file when you call the function with his parameters.

```
from lxml import etree

root = etree.Element("UpdateInventoryRequest")
doc = etree.ElementTree(root)

start_date_sard = root.append(etree.Element("StartDate"))
room_id_sard = root.append(etree.Element("RoomId"))
root.append(etree.Element("Data"))
data_root = root[2]
availability_in_data = data_root.append(etree.Element("Availability"))
price_in_data = data_root.append(etree.Element("Price"))


def buildXmlUpdate(dfrom, roomId, ldays):   

    start_date_sard.text = dfrom
    roomId = str(roomId)  
    room_id_sard.text = roomId


    for n in ldays:
        print (dfrom, roomId, n)
        #availability_in_data.text = get.ldays['avail']
        #price_in_data.txt = get.ldays['price']
        ldays[-1]['avail'] = str(ldays[-1]['avail'])
        ldays[-1]['price'] =str(ldays[-1]['price'])
        availability_in_data.text = ldays[-1]['avail']
        price_in_data.text = ldays[-1]['price']


#here execute the function 

buildXmlUpdate('21/12/2015', 1, [{'avail': 1, 'price': 100}, {'avail': 3, 'price': 120}])
doc.write('testoutput.xml', pretty_print=True)
```

And this is what i receive:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

What happen?

Comment: can you please add a stack trace ? so we can know where the error occurred ?

Comment: Probably `root.append()` returns `None`.

Comment: File "connect_sard_wubook_II.py", line 7, in <module>
    start_date_sard.text =""
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:

```
from lxml import etree
# Create Xml
root = etree.Element("UpdateInventoryRequest")
doc = etree.ElementTree(root)

root.append(etree.Element("StartDate"))
root.append(etree.Element("RoomId"))
root.append(etree.Element("Data"))
data_root = root[2]
data_root.append(etree.Element("Availability"))
data_root.append(etree.Element("Price"))
# Xml in code

def buildXmlUpdate(dfrom, roomId, ldays):   
    start_date_sard = dfrom
    roomId = str(roomId)  
    room_id_sard = roomId

    for n in ldays:
        print (dfrom, roomId, n)
        ldays[-1]['avail'] = str(ldays[-1]['avail'])
        ldays[-1]['price'] =str(ldays[-1]['price'])
        availability_in_data = ldays[-1]['avail']
        price_in_data = ldays[-1]['price']

    root[0].text = start_date_sard
    root[1].text = room_id_sard
    data_root[0].text = availability_in_data
    data_root[1].text = price_in_data

#here execute the function 

buildXmlUpdate('21/12/2015', 1, [{'avail': 1, 'price': 100}, {'avail': 3, 'price': 120}])
doc.write('testoutput.xml', pretty_print=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

according to the [lxml tutorial](http://lxml.de/tutorial.html) you should access a node using the object you created and not the return value of the `append` function.

Example:

```
root = etree.Element("UpdateInventoryRequest")
root.text = "this is a text"
```